Unable to join the AD in ubuntu 24.04 version
via centrify mode we are trying to join the AD, But getting failed and we are getting the error as below.
!!! Dependency error!!!
The Following packages, When installed, must be the version: Centrifydc,CentrifyDC.openssl,CentrifyDC-openldap and CentrifyDC-curl.
